# How to access list permutations in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, permutation, prolog-dif

I want to access list permutation and pass it as argument to other functions.

This is the permutation code:

```
takeout(X,[X|R],R).  
takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S]) :-
   takeout(X,R,S),
   write(S).

perm([X|Y],Z) :-
   perm(Y,W),
   takeout(X,Z,W).  
perm([],[]).
```

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly. What are you running that isn't working? What do you want to see, but aren't seeing, or seeing that you don't want to see?

Comment: I want to get a list of number from user, and show all max-heap trees, so i need the permutation of list and send it as a parametr to max-heap function,(sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To start with, let's redefine your predicates so they don't do any unnecessary I/O:

```
takeout(X,[X|R],R).  
takeout(X,[F |R],[F|S]) :- takeout(X,R,S).

perm([X|Y],Z) :- perm(Y,W), takeout(X,Z,W).  
perm([],[]).
```

Now you have what could be considered a "pure" permutation function:

```
?- perm([1,2,3], X).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
X = [2, 1, 3] ;
X = [2, 3, 1] ;
X = [1, 3, 2] ;
X = [3, 1, 2] ;
X = [3, 2, 1] ;
false.
```

So, suppose you have a max_heap function that takes a list of values and produces a tree. I'll let you worry about that, so let's just posit that it exists and is called `max_heap/2` and let's further posit that you have a way to display this attractively called `display_heap/1`. To "take" the permutation and "send" it as a parameter to these functions, you're really saying in math-ese: suppose P is a permutation of X, let's make a max_heap with it and display it. Or, suppose P is a permutation of X, H is a max heap made from X, let's display H:

```
show_heaps(List) :- perm(List, P), max_heap(P, H), display_heap(H).
```

This says the same thing as my English sentence: suppose P is a permutation of the list, then H is a heap representation of it, then display it. Technically, `display_heap/1` is still a predicate which could be true or false for a given heap. In practice, it will always be true, and if you run this you'll still have to hit `;` repeatedly to say, give me another solution, unless you use a failure-driven loop or an extralogical predicate like `findall/3` to cause all the solutions to be found.

**Edit**: Let's discuss failure-driven loops and `findall/3`. First let me add some new predicates, because I don't know exactly what you're doing, but it doesn't matter for our purposes.

```
double([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :- Y is X*2, double(Xs, Ys).
double([],[]).

showlist(Xs) :- print(Xs).
```

So now I have a predicate `double/2` which doubles the values in the list and a predicate `showlist/1` that prints the list on standard output. We can try it out like so:

```
?- perm([1,2,3], X), double(X, Y), showlist(Y).
[2,4,6]
X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = [2, 4, 6] ;
[4,2,6]
X = [2, 1, 3],
Y = [4, 2, 6] ;
[4,6,2]
X = [2, 3, 1],
Y = [4, 6, 2] ;
[2,6,4]
X = [1, 3, 2],
Y = [2, 6, 4] ;
[6,2,4]
X = [3, 1, 2],
Y = [6, 2, 4] ;
[6,4,2]
X = [3, 2, 1],
Y = [6, 4, 2] ;
false.
```

When you type `;` you're saying, "or?" to Prolog. In other words, you're saying "what else?" You're telling Prolog, in effect, this isn't the answer I want, try and find me another answer I like better. You can formalize this process with a failure-driven loop:

```
?- perm([1,2,3], X), double(X, Y), showlist(Y), fail.
[2,4,6][4,2,6][4,6,2][2,6,4][6,2,4][6,4,2]
false.
```

So now you see the output from each permutation having gone through `double/2` there, and then Prolog reported false. That's what one means by something like this:

```
show_all_heaps(List) :- perm(List, X), double(X, Y), showlist(Y), nl, fail.
show_all_heaps(_).
```

Look at how that works:

```
?- show_all_heaps([1,2,3]).
[2,4,6]
[4,2,6]
[4,6,2]
[2,6,4]
[6,2,4]
[6,4,2]
true.
```

The other option is using `findall/3`, which looks more like this:

```
?- findall(Y, (perm([1,2,3], X), double(X, Y)), Ys).
Ys = [[2, 4, 6], [4, 2, 6], [4, 6, 2], [2, 6, 4], [6, 2, 4], [6, 4, 2]].
```

Using this to solve your problem is probably beyond the scope of whatever homework it is you're working on though.

Comment: i didn't understand your mean "unless you use a failure-driven loop or an extralogical predicate like findall/3 to cause all the solutions to be found."???????

Comment: I added some explanation of that to my answer.

Comment: Can you explain why flipping the order of the conditions in the antecedent for the if-clause of `perm` causes a stack overflow?

Comment: @user129393192 I'm afraid I don't understand your question since there is no if-clause in `perm`, I don't see what I said about stack overflows in this 12-year-old answer. Perhaps you should open a separate question.

Comment: Isn't this `perm([X|Y],Z) :- perm(Y,W), takeout(X,Z,W).` an if-clause?

Comment: @user129393192 Not in any sense I would use. I recommend you ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

We can define `list_permutation/2` based on [`same_length/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dlists.html) and [`select/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select) like this:

```
:- use_module(library(lists),[same_length/2,select/3]).

list_permutation(As,Bs) :-
   same_length(As,Bs),          % redundant goal helps termination
   list_permutation_(As,Bs).

list_permutation_([],[]).
list_permutation_([A|As],Bs0) :-
    select(A,Bs0,Bs),
    list_permutation_(As,Bs).
```

Thanks to `same_length/2`, both of the following queries<sup>1,2</sup> terminate universally:

```
?- list_permutation([1,2,3],Ys).
  Ys = [1,2,3]
; Ys = [1,3,2]
; Ys = [2,1,3]
; Ys = [3,1,2]
; Ys = [2,3,1]
; Ys = [3,2,1]
; false.

?- list_permutation(Xs,[1,2,3]).
  Xs = [1,2,3]
; Xs = [1,3,2]
; Xs = [2,1,3]
; Xs = [2,3,1]
; Xs = [3,1,2]
; Xs = [3,2,1]
; false.
```

So far, so good. But what does the answer sequence look like if there are duplicate list items?

```
?- list_permutation([1,1,1],Ys).
  Ys = [1,1,1]
; Ys = [1,1,1]
; Ys = [1,1,1]
; Ys = [1,1,1]
; Ys = [1,1,1]
; Ys = [1,1,1]
; false.
```

5/6 answers are redundant! What can we do? We simply **use [`selectd/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207770/4609915)** instead of [`select/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select)!

```
list_permuted(As,Bs) :-
   same_length(As,Bs),
   list_permuted_(As,Bs).

list_permuted_([],[]).
list_permuted_([A|As],Bs0) :-
   selectd(A,Bs0,Bs),           % use selectd/3, not select/3
   list_permuted_(As,Bs).
```

Let's re-run above query that gave us 5 redundant solutions before!

```
?- list_permuted([1,1,1],Ys).
  Ys = [1,1,1]
; false.

?- list_permuted(Xs,[1,1,1]).
  Xs = [1,1,1]
; false.
```

**Better!** All redundant answers are gone.

Let's compare the solution set for some sample case:

```
?- _Xs = [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1],
   setof(Ys,list_permutation(_Xs,Ys),Yss),
   setof(Ys,list_permuted(_Xs,Ys),Yss),
   length(Yss,N).
N = 84, Yss = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2],[...|...]|...].
```

OK! How about empirical runtime measurements with a problem of a slightly bigger size?

We use [`call_time/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823841/4609915) for measuring the runtime in milli-seconds `T_ms`.

```
?- call_time(\+ (list_permutation([1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1],_),false),T_ms).
T_ms = 8110.

?- call_time(\+ (list_permuted(   [1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1],_),false),T_ms).
T_ms = 140.
```

OK! And with proper compilation of `if_/3` and `(=)/3`, `list_permuted/2` is even faster!

---

<sup>Footnote 1: Using SICStus Prolog version 4.3.2 (x86_64-linux-glibc2.12).</sup>

<sup>Footnote 2: The answers given by the Prolog toplevel have been post-processed for the sake of readability.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to explore the permutations without the "False" in the end, this code might be helpful

```
takeout(X,[F |R],[F|S]) :- F\=X, takeout(X,R,S).
takeout(X,[X|R],R).
perm([X|Y],Z) :- perm(Y,W), takeout(X,Z,W).  
perm([],[]).
```

So, the output of perm([a,b],B) would be

```
B=[a,b]
B=[b,a]
```