# Prolog, permutation code understanding

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to understand how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134380/how-to-access-list-permutations-in-prolog/9135257#9135257) program works.

Code from Daniel Lyons' solution(from the link above)

```
takeout(X,[X|R],R).  
takeout(X,[F |R],[F|S]) :- takeout(X,R,S).

perm([X|Y],Z) :- perm(Y,W), takeout(X,Z,W).  
perm([],[]).
```

I'm trying ti understand how it works with this list `[1,2,3]`
So, I have `perm([1,2,3],X).`

It's easy to understand at first, `Y = [2,3]` then `Y = [3]` and then `Y = []`

After that `perm([],[]).` is called and it gives us `W = []`

Now, `takeout` is called for the first time - `takeout(3, Z, []).`
It returns `Z =  [3]`

Now, we are going back, where `perm([],[]).` gives us `W = [3]`, (because Y was [3] at this point)

Same as above, `takeout(2, Z, [3])` and `Z = [2, 3]`.

Again `perm([], []).` and `W = [2, 3]`.

And `takeout(1, Z, [2, 3])`, which gives us first answer `Z = [1, 2, 3]`

Here I don't know why program don't end , recursion is done, so why `takeout` and `perm` are working again ?

After that `takeout` is called `takeout(1, [2,3])`.

Which now works with `takeout(X,[F |R],[F|S])` and not with `takeout(X,[X|R],R).` and that's my second question, why?

Comment: In Prolog, a query or predicate call will attempt to find *all* possible solutions, not just one and then end. So even though it looks like they end, they've left a choice point in which other options for success are possible. Prolog automatically goes back to these choice points and provides the alternatives. That's part of the power of Prolog.

Comment: @lurker Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog, a predicate's behavior is quite unlike that of a function in procedural languages. A *function* is called to perform a task, it executes, and then comes back returning some values or having performed some side effects, or both.

A *predicate* defines a relation and/or set of facts that establish a logical connection between it's arguments. When a query is made to a predicate in Prolog, Prolog will attempt to find *every* instantiation of the argument variables that will make that predicate succeed (be true).

In a very simple case, I might have the following facts:

```
likes(tom, mary).    % Tom likes Mary
likes(fred, mary).   % Fred likes Mary
```

Here I have one predicate or fact, `likes`, which defines a relation between two people. We call the above *facts* because they each specify a precise, concrete relation with fully instantiated arguments. I can make a query to determine *Who likes Mary?* as follows:

```
| ?- likes(Person, mary).

Person = tom ? ;

Person = fred

yes
```

The query first comes back with `Person = tom` but indicates it has more options to check once it has found that `Person = tom` satisfies the query. Entering `;` tells Prolog to continue with the next solution (if there is one), and it finds it: `Person = fred`.

Now let's consider `takeout/3`. This is a *predicate* which defines a *relation* between a set of *variables*.

1. `takeout(X,[X|R],R).`
2. `takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S]) :- takeout(X,R,S).`

The `takeout/3` predicate has two *predicate clauses* or *rules* for the relation. It's helpful to try to read them:

1. `R` is what you get if you take `X` out of `[X|R]`.
2. `[F|S]` is what you get if you take `X` out of `[F|R]` *if* `S` is what you get when you take `X` out of `R`.

Prolog looks at multiple clauses in a disjunctive way. That is, a query or call to the predicate will succeed if *any one* of the rules can hold true. When a query on `takeout/3` is made, Prolog will look for instantiations of the given variables in the query which will make it true, and it will attempt to find *every* such instantiation that does so. In other words, if there's more than one way to satisfy the condition, it will *backtrack* and attempt to find those variables instantiations that do so.

Consider the query:

```
?- takeout(X, [1,2,3], R).
```

Prolog is able to match this to the first predicate clause: `takeout(X, [X|R], R)` as `takeout(1, [1,2,3], [2,3])` by instantiating `X = 1` and `R = [2,3]`. So this query will succeed with the following result:

```
R = [2,3]
X = 1 ?
```

But we see that Prolog is indicating there are more options to explore. That's because there's another clause: `takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S])` which matches the query, `takeout(X, [1,2,3], R)`. Prolog therefore *backtracks* and attempts the second clause, which matches:

```
takeout(X, [1|[2,3]], [1|S]) :-    % F = 1, R = [2,3]
    takeout(X, [2,3], S).
```

Prolog will then follow the recursive call `takeout(X, [2,3], S)` and *start from the first clause again* and attemp to match `takeout(X, [2,3], S)` with `takeout(X, [X|R], R)`, which succeeds with `X = 2` and `S = [3]` (`takeout(2, [2|[3]], [3]).`. The recursion unwinds or returns (as it would in any language), and the previous call head, `takeout(X, [1|[2,3]], [1|S])` then ends up instantiating as: `takeout(1, [1|[2,3]], [1|[3]])`. So we get:

```
R = [2,3]
X = 1 ? ;

R = [1,3]    % that is, [1|[3]]
X = 2 ?
```

And so on. Similar behavior applies to `perm`. In the context of the query `perm`, the calls to `takeout` backtrack to produce additional results, so `perm` produces additional results (since its calls to `takeout` backtrack, just like they do when you query `takeout` by hand).

---

As noted by @false, the predicate `takeout/3` is implemented as a standard predicate in Prolog as `select/3`.

Comment: This takeout is commonly called [`select/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select)

Comment: @false indeed, I recognize it. :)