# Get predicate execution time in seconds

Tags: prolog

I'm looking a way to get the time execution of a predicate in seconds, using swi-prolog. I found the `time(X)` who brings me this information and much more, but what I need is only the time in seconds, wath I would like to write after run the predicate.

There is a way to do that?

Comment: Check out `statistics/2`: Measure the time difference before and after calling the goal.

Comment: try `?- profile(your_predicate).` then enjoy the graphical interface...

Comment: `statistics(runtime,[Start_ms,Last_ms])` works the same way as in SICStus, YAP, B, GNU.

Answer (score 2):

To get the elapsed runtime passed while executing a specified goal you can use [`call_time/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823841/4609915):

```
?- call_time(true,T_ms).
T_ms = 0.
```

Be aware that `T_ms` measures milliseconds, not seconds!

To get to seconds use an additional goal like `T is T_ms * 0.001`.

For a list of concrete uses of `call_time/2`, look at [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D%20call_time).