# Display the execution times for each goal of a predicate clause

Tags: prolog

I want to see the execution time inside goals of predicate with **SICStus Prolog**.

**Example :**

```
pred :-
   goal1,
   time,
   goal2,
   time.

go :-
   call(pred).

time_go :-
   go,
   times(go).
```

**Expected result:**

```
?- time_go.
times_go = 1000ms ,   
times_go_goal1 = 500ms,
times_go_goal2 = 500ms
```

How to do that ?

I tried `time_out(:Goal, +Time, -Result)` from `library(timeout)` but I got this error:

```
| ?- time_out(char_code(a,N), T, Res).
! Instantiation error in argument 2 of user:time_out/3
! goal:  time_out(user:char_code(a,_193),_179,_181)

| ?- time_out(char_code(a,N), 1000, Res).
N = 97,
Res = success ? ; % Res=timeout in other example
```

Comment: I think that one of `statistics/0` or `statistics/2` is the solution , any idea ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `statistics/2` for that:

```
statistics(runtime,[Start|_]),
do_something,
statistics(runtime,[Stop|_]),
Runtime is Stop - Start.
```

Alternatively, you can use `total_runtime` instead of `runtime` if you want to include time for garbage collection. `Start` and `Stop` are measured in milliseconds, but the last time I used it with SICStus it returned only multiple of 10. In a project we used calls to a custom external C library to retrieve a finer resolution.

A remark to `time_out/3`: It is used to limit the runtime of a goal, not to measure its runtime. If the goal finishes in time, the result is `success`, if it needs more time the execution is aborted (internally a timeout exception is thrown) and the result is `timeout`.

Comment: thank you, also for `time_out` ,I know  but i thought that it is possible when i put a variable it would loaded by suitable time ., regard to `statistics/2`, i add  `format('go/2 took ~3d sec.~n', [Runtime]).` to obtain a nice outcome ; `| go/2 took 0.015 sec. ` Instead of `Time=15`

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add two thoughts:

1. Prolog allows for backtracking, so goals *may* succeed more than once.

   What's the "runtime" you are interested in?

   - Only the work for computing the previous answer?
   - Or rather the total time?
2. Use [`statistics/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dstatistics.html#index-statistics_002f_005b0_002c2_005d-_0028built_002din_002c-ref-page_0029-1), but don't do it directly. 
   Instead, use an abstraction like 
   [`call_time/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823841/4609915).

Sample query:

```
?- call_time((permutation([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i],Xs),Xs=[_,_,g,f,e,d,c,b,a]), T_ms).
   Xs = [h, i, g, f, e, d, c, b, a], T_ms = 304
;  Xs = [i, h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a], T_ms = 345
;  false.
```

Notice that `call_time/2` succeeds *twice* and `T_ms` measures *total* runtime up to this point.

Comment: thanks, although I found only these built-in predicates in _SICStus-prolog_;
`call/[1..255], callable/1, call_cleanup/2, call_residue_vars/2`

Comment: `call_time` is based on `call` and `statistics`. I embedded 3 links above. Follow the white rabbit...

Comment: exactly what I do, `go(In,Out) :- statistics(runtime,[Start|_]),
                      pred(In,Out),
                      statistics(runtime,[Stop|_]),
                      Runtime is Stop - Start,
                      format('go/2 took ~3d sec.~n', [Runtime]).`

Comment: @AnsPiter. Kind of, but `call_time/2` is somewhat more versatile: (1) It keeps code for time measurement and code for I/O separate. (2) And, being a [tag:meta-predicate], it can be used with arbitrary goals having any numbers of arguments.

Comment: in SWI, I had to call `use_module(library(statistics)).` at the REPL first. :)

Comment: @WillNess. Really? I was under the impression that `statistics/2` is in module `system`, at least it is with version 7.6.4... which version are you referring to?

Comment: @WillNess. It seems to be a 'builtin' predicate in SICStus and GNU Prolog, too... YMMV:)

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody mentioned it, if you only want a time display the [time/1](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/docs/05_run/10_docu/02_reference/07_theories/06_reflect/05_stats.html) predicate can be also useful. It is already supported by a couple of Prolog systems such as SWI-Prolog, Jekejeke Prolog, O-Prolog, etc...:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.7.19)

?- time((between(1,10000000,_), fail; true)).
% 10,000,001 inferences, 0.453 CPU in 0.468 seconds (97% CPU, 22068968 Lips)
true.
```

Unfortunately Prolog systems such as GNU Prolog, SICStus Prolog dont support it. But its the analog of the Unix [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29) command, in that it is a meta predicate that takes a goal argument. Better than stone age methods.

Comment: This can be found in the [statistics](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=statistics) grabbag. Time should really have a version which unifies the actual data with variables. Why~~~

Comment: You mean like ms/2 from LPA Prolog?